# Intellij not finding Python modules installed via pip

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I have installed the `nltk` package via `sudo pip install nltk` and it works fine:

```
21:07:00/~ $python -c "import nltk"
```

Just to be sure there were no clashing with `brew` pip I also did:

```
21:06:24/~ $python -m pip install nltk
Requirement already satisfied: nltk in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from nltk)
```

So both brew and system python are happy together.

Intellij is another story.  The basic python is working but the pip installed libraries are MIA:

[image]

Here are the relevant SDK settings:

Module level:

[image]

Project level:

[image]

So what is needed in this project to have pip libraries welcomed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to the `brew` installed python fixed the issue.

[image]

And here it is with `nltk` resolving now:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Also add your site-packages path in in your project classpath if you still get import error

e.g. `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Answer (score 2):

The path you try to install the package is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, so I suppose `pip` works for the Python which is installed by `brew`, but the project interpreter is the system Python.

So maybe you should use `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python` path.

You can run this to check out the Python version and pip version that you're using:

```
  ~ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
  ~ ls -al /usr/local/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ** ** /usr/local/bin/python@ -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/python

  ~ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
  ~ ls -al /usr/local/bin/pip
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ** ** /usr/local/bin/pip@ -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin/pip
```

I suggest Mac OS users install another Python and do not use the system version, this will protect your system Python tasks. Also another idea is to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) which is a tool to create isolated Python environments.

Hope this helps.