# importing lxml on Intellij throws "no such module," despite successful pip install

Tags: python, intellij-idea, lxml, python-import

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934646/what-is-the-best-way-to-import-new-python-modules-in-intellij/48936028#48936028) detailing my problem with installing python modules through Intellij, and the answer I accepted there (running \venv\Scipts\activate to activate my virtual environment, and then using pip install module_name) initially worked. However, it seems I have run into another snag with importing modules despite what I have tried in the previous post:

[image]

I've successfully installed lxml using pip from the Intellij terminal. I have my `import lxml` at the top of my file, and rather being immediately detected as a nonexistent module by Intellij (red underline), it simply grays it out as an unused import statement. However, when I run my code, it then throws an error saying there is no module named lxml

Unlike before with beautifulSoup, since the error isn't caught before(?) compile time by Intellij, I don't have the option of hitting Alt + Enter and installing the module. I'm honestly out of ideas, and I don't understand why the behavior for installing bs4 is different from what I'm experiencing now with lxml. I feel like there must be some initialization I'm missing within Intellij to cause all these problems, but as I detailed in the previous post, I've been through most recommended in previous questions.

Comment: Which python  interpreter is Intellij running?

Comment: It says "Python 3.6(MP2_WebScraper) C:\Users\Lily\IdeaProjects\MP2_WebScaper\venv\scripts\python.exe".  Also, I recently renamed the package the file I'm importing lxml into is in, not sure if that would've changed anything

Comment: In the image shown, it does not look like your virtualenv is activated. It usual writes `(venv)` in the CMD line

Comment: ah, that's probably it, I guess I had a mistaken idea of "activation." Thank you