# Python packages shown in the Intellij python sdk explorer are not found by the interpreter

Tags: python, intellij-idea

Consider a typical set of python packages in the brew-based 3.7 SDK - in particular *numpy* and *pandas* shown as the last couple in the dialog box:

[image]

However none of *pandas*,  _numpy, or even *collections* (which is a core library) are being found by the interpreter:

[image]

I have also exited and restarted Intellij to see whether the skeletons needed to be regenerated and/or re-loaded but that had no effect.  Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Note I had a similar question from two years ago: [Intellij not finding Python modules installed via pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44015425/intellij-not-finding-python-modules-installed-via-pip) . But in that case resetting the interpreter to the *brew* installed version fixed it: in this case as shown in the first screenshot the interpreter is *already* set to brew version.

I am using `Intellij Ultimate 2019.1`

**Note**  The same approach to doing business *works fine* in *pycharm* :

[image]

Comment: First of all, let's determine if the issue is IDE-related. Try running the same script from your system terminal, using the same interpreter. Do you get the same error?

Comment: That was already verified in both _python_ and _ipython_ REPL's many times